# Aiko scores a goal five times, given that she scored a goal at least three times (Binomial).

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, word-problem

Aiko is a keen basketball player and knows that her chance of scoring a basket on any one throw is 0.65. If Aiko takes 6 shots for a goal, find the probability, (correct to 4 decimal places and put a 0 in front of the decimal point), that she scores a goal five times, given that she scored a goal at least three times.

Taken $$binomPcf(6,0.65,3) = 0.2355$$ and $$binomPcf(6,0.65,3) = 0.2437$$

$$\frac{0.2355}{0.2437}=0.9664$$

But the answer is 0.2761...

Comment: what is binomPcf, and do you get different answers when the inputs are the same?

Comment: It's another way of saying 6c5*(0.65)^5*(0.35)^1 and 6c3*(0.65)^3*(0.35)^3

Comment: You probably need to sum binomPcf(6, 0.65, k) for k = 5 to 6, as well as the sum of binomPcf(6, 0.65, k) for k = 3 to 6, and divide the former sum by the latter.

Comment: I tried that, but got 0.3615. Not 0.2761 (is there any other way)?

Answer (score 2):

The probabilities that Aika gets exactly $0$, $1$, and $2$ successes are

$$0.35^6\,\,\,$$

$$0.35^5 \cdot 0.65 \cdot 6\,\,\,$$

$$ 0.35^4 \cdot 0.65^2 \cdot 15\,\,$$

respectively. The sum of these is $\approx 0.1174\,\,\,$. So the probability that she gets at least $3$ goals is

$$1-0.1174 \approx 0.8826\,\,\,\,$$

The probablity that she gets exactly $5$ goals is

$$ 0.65^5 \cdot 0.35 \cdot 6 \approx 0.2437 \,$$

So the searched probability is

$$\frac{0.2437}{0.8826}\approx 0.2761$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer 0.2761 is correct (I approximated along the way, so there might be errors in the last digit or so); the question should have specified EXACTLY 5 times.

So, you need to find the probability of the event that she hits at least 3 (so, she hits either 3, 4, 5, or 6 (the way I did it was that she doesn't hit 0 or 1 or 2, which is also valid)) and find the probability that she hits exactly 5. It works; just try it a couple more times.

(Also, I would have put this as a comment, but I don't have commenting privileges so if someone wants to move this to the comments, they can)

Comment: Looks answer shaped to me.

Comment: I did not write it out step by step so I wasn't sure if this would qualify as an answer (new here to writing things so not a great judge of what should be an answer and what should be a comment); thanks for letting me know!